# botocore.errorfactory.DBInstanceNotFoundFault in boto3

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, boto3, aws-cli

How to catch this boto error `botocore.errorfactory.DBInstanceNotFoundFault`

This is my python3 code :

```
import boto3
import botocore.exceptions
import botocore.errorfactory

clientrds = boto3.client('rds')

rdsInstances = ['prod-rds']


for rds in rdsInstances : 
    rds_response = clientrds.describe_db_instances(DBInstanceIdentifier=rds)
    DBInstanceStatus = (rds_response["DBInstances"][0]["DBInstanceStatus"])
    if DBInstanceStatus == "stopped" :
        print(rds," Switched On ")
    start_rds_response = clientrds.start_db_instance(DBInstanceIdentifier=rds)
```

console output / Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rds.py", line 11, in <module>
    rds_response = clientrds.describe_db_instances(DBInstanceIdentifier=rds)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 391, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 719, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.DBInstanceNotFoundFault: An error occurred (DBInstanceNotFound) when calling the DescribeDBInstances operation: DBInstance prod-rds not found.
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: updated my question.@ErmiyaEskandary, try to understand the question/error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Able to handle the execption using  botocore.exceptions

```
for rds in rdsInstances : 
try :
    start_rds_response = clientrds.start_db_instance(DBInstanceIdentifier=rds)  #RDS.instance.start
except botocore.errorfactory.ClientError as error:
    if error.response['Error']['Code'] == 'DBInstanceNotFound': 
        print("DBInstanceNotFound")
```

Ref : [Link](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/error-handling.html#botocore-exceptions)